# input text is loosing focus using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have this input text:

```
<input key={['event', indexEventType].join('_')} type="text" name="name" defaultValue={eventType.name} style={{ width: 100 + '%' }} onChange={(value) => this.handleChangeEventType(value, indexEventType)} />
```

When I write something on that combobox I can only type once and the cursor goes away.
 I have seen this link that explains why that happens but the solution that is available there doesn't work for me.
The `handleChange` method isn't the problem too because I have various inputs using that same `handleChange` and all of them work except this one.

I know why this happens, my variable name that I am trying to input is somehow interfering with the name on the props (`name="name"`).

The variable that I am setting the input value has too be called name.

Is there any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The property name="name" probably isn't your problem here.

Loosing focus of an input is usually the result of a key changing.
Whenever you change the key of a component React will fully remount it resulting in an entirely new element. Since you never interacted with this new element React won't keep the cursor in it.

Try to set a static key or one that doesn't change based upon the users input and check if your problem is gone.

Comment: how do I set  static key? I have a key already and I know that it is unique @Berouminum

Comment: @pedroalmeida In your case either make sure that `['event', indexEventType].join('_')` always returns the same value while the user is typing or, to test if this is actually your problem, set it to a static value like `key="myInput"`

Comment: its not working @Berouminum, i put this:                                              <input key='test' type="text" name="name" defaultValue={eventType.name} style={{ width: 100 + '%' }} onChange={(value) => this.handleChangeEventType(value, indexEventType)} />

Comment: @pedroalmeida Is there an element above your input with a key which could potentially change? Please edit your question and add more code.